# Erro c# e MySql: Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords

Tags: c#, mysql, asp, connectionstring

**Contexto:** 
Temos uma aplicação construída há alguns anos em ASP 6 que acessa um banco de dados MySql, lá na LocalWeb. Para fazer a conexão, a aplicação se utiliza do driver MySQL ODBC 5.1. e funciona perfeitamente. 
**Objetivo:**
 Estamos construindo um novo sistema c# mvc que deve utilizar o mesmo banco, mas desta vez estamos utilizando o driver MySql.Data versão 6.10.4.
**Problema:** Quando tentamos conectar no mesmo banco, obtemos o erro `Message: Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.`

Verifiquei alguns posts em que a solução apontada era executar este script:

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0;
SET PASSWORD FOR my_user=PASSWORD('my_password');
```

A duvida que temos aqui é: Se fizermos essa alteração, o sistema antigo vai parar de funcionar?
Alguém aqui do fórum já passou por isso? Já agradeço.

Comment: Não vai parar de funcionar.
Coloque o resultado final para gente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não, o sistema antigo não deixa de funcionar porque todas as dependências à partida são *backwards compatible*. Mas nada melhor que criar um branch do projecto e testar. Caso algo corra mal tem sempre o projecto original.
Eventualmente poderá ter que ir ao projecto antigo e mudar a senha para a nova senha mas não acredito.

De qualquer das maneiras resta unicamente testar, se preferir crie um banco de dados auxiliar e teste o acesso.